# Idea find and replace with capture groups

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I'm trying to find

```
 @BindView($ResId) internal lateinit var $FieldName: $Class
```

And replace with

```
private val $FieldName by bindView<$Class>($ResId)
```

What's the syntax to do that with Intellij Find & Replace feature?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, we have to activate the checkbox **Regex** in the *Find & Replace* bar if it should only affect the current file, or in the *Replace in Path* dialog for the whole project:

[image]

Using this regular expression with 3 capturing groups in the **Find** text field should work:

```
@BindView\((.*)\) internal lateinit var (.*): (.*)
```

Now we can use the variables `$1` for $ResId, `$2` for $FieldName and `$3`for $Class in the **Replace** text field:

```
private val $2 by bindView<$3>($1)
```

Comment: Could you clarify brackets logic? Why .* is in brackets (.*)?

Comment: With the regular expression ``foo .* bar`` you just can check if an input is matching or not, but you can not extract any values from the input. If you want to match a regular expression and extract values from it, you have to use capturing groups, which are  denoted by brackets. So if the  regular express ``foo (.*) bar`` is matching the input you also can extract the value between foo and bar. The capturing groups are numbered by her occurence order starting by 1. The $0 is the whole string if the input matches.